# Can't move image down whlie holding the button

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new in coding and I'm sorry if I seem dumb. I purchased tutorial for beginners and following what he does on the screen. This code is from tutorial

```
`import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900,700))


finished = False
x = 380
y = 300
index = [0,1,2,3,4]
array = [0,1.2,4.5]
playerImage = pygame.image.load("Player.png")
playerImage.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
playerImage = pygame.transform.scale(playerImage, (90,120))
playerImage = playerImage.convert_alpha()
backgroundImage = pygame.image.load("ground.png")
backgroundImage = pygame.transform.scale(backgroundImage,(900,700))
screen.blit(backgroundImage,(0,0))

frame = pygame.time.Clock()
while finished == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        finished = True


     pressedKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
     if pressedKeys[pygame.K_SPACE] == 1:
         y -= 5
     #rectOne = pygame.Rect(x,y,100,100)
     color = (0,0,255)
     black = (0,0,0)
     screen.blit(backgroundImage,(0,0))
     screen.blit(playerImage,(x,y))
     #pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,rect)
     pygame.display.flip()
     frame.tick(30)`
```

I wrote exact same code what he was showing in video. Everything works fine except for my player image goes down on pressing button but with holding nothing happens. I did exactly what he explained. For him it works but not for me. My Python version is "2.7.14". Pygame is "1.9.3". Thanks.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What's the desired behavior? Do you want to move the image up or down? It's moving up when I press the space bar and it's moving continuously.

Comment: Works for me, too. Except it moves up the screen, not down.

Comment: When I press Space image moves down, no issues with that unless its not moving continuously while holding the button.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The continuous movement must be in the application loop and not in the event loop. The application loop runs once per frame, but the event loop only runs once per event. When a key is pressed a `KEYDOWN` event occurs and when a key is released a `KEYUP` event occurs, but there is no event when a key is held down:

```py
while finished == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finished = True

    # INDENTATION

    #<--|

    pressedKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressedKeys[pygame.K_SPACE] == 1:
        y -= 5
    #rectOne = pygame.Rect(x,y,100,100)
    color = (0,0,255)
    black = (0,0,0)
    screen.blit(backgroundImage,(0,0))
    screen.blit(playerImage,(x,y))
    #pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    frame.tick(30)`
```

In your code, the indentation problem is barely noticeable as the indentation is only 1 space. You should use at least 2 spaces.